# UIViewAnimateWithDuration completion never called

Tags: ios, uiview, animatewithduration

I am using the `UIView animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` method but the completion method is never getting called. Here is my code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^
             {
                 //random lines of code

             }completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 if (finished)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"FINISHED");
                 }
             }];
```

**EDIT:** When I comment out the lines in my `animations:` it gets called???!!!

These are the lines:

```
CGFloat objectY = object.frame.origin.y;
objectY += speed;
object.frame = CGRectMake(object.frame.origin.x, objectY, 75, 75);
```

Comment: Is it called if you comment those random lines out? Or did you try to add else clause into completion block?

Comment: @MertBuran Yes. Why is that happening???

Comment: What are the random lines?

Comment: depends on the lines. what did the lines look like?

Comment: And `object` is an instance of `UIView` (or subclass thereof)?

Comment: What is the variable `speed`?

Comment: @bachonk It is a float

Comment: I tried your code and it prints out "FINISHED", I extended duration and checked if userInteraction blocks completion handler but it didn't change. Your problem should be anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am taking a guess - you want to animate the movement of a continuous gesture?
If yes, the animation never ends due the user interaction.

Just update the frame, no UIView Animation. Should work just fine.

Comment: I think what you're saying here is that removing the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` will allow the completion to be handled

Comment: Maybe. Its to less code to tell what is actual happening. The UIViewAnimation you made is fine. Must be something interfering. Where comes the speed from or how often get this animation called for instance? Setting the origin of a frame in an animation is about moving a distance, but not speed. speed is distance divided by time, but you had something in mind when you did choose the name for the float. Like I said before, I am guessing:)